# Depth of any node x in Weighted Quick-Union Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

I know from Sedgewick's book on algorithms that the max depth of any node x from a set of N nodes is at most log2(N) applying the algorithm(which says to put the shorter tree beneath to avoid tall trees) and he gives an understandable proof by induction. The thing is that I have trouble visualising that result apart form the mathematical manipulations, I mean besides proving that that assumption is correct my question is how do you get to that assumption.
This are some remarks he makes before the proof:

1)The depth of the node x increases by one when merged to another tree

2)When the depth increases the size of the tree at least doubles.

But here is the thing, he says : "The size of the tree containing x can double at most log2N times" And I don't understand why.

Here is the link to a presentation he gave on the topic. http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/15UnionFind-2x2.pdf the proof's sketch is on slide 33.

Thanks :)

Comment: " how do you get to that assumption" - What assumption?   I can't understand your question.  Actually, there is not even a question in there.  Please edit your question to make it a lot clearer what you are asking (what you are a looking for an answer to).  Also, show us what you've tried.  Have you tried working through some examples?  Questions like "please explain this proof to me" are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry,  I wasn't trying for you to explain me the proof, I get the proof. I just wanted to go a little beyond the math. And yes, I've worked through some examples trying to get the grasp of it and also some variants trying to see the limiting behaviour of the restriction i.e when it is exactly log2N. Eventually I figured out what FrankW answered which is exactly what I was looking for, going backwards. But, you are right I should've been more concrete with my question I am sorry about that. I did't want to look as if I was trying to avoid working/thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of a tree starts at 1 and doubles $i$ times, it will be $2^i$ (at least -- there might be other size increases as well). If $i>\log_2N$ this would give a size $>N$ -- more than the total number of nodes.

Comment: thanks a lot, I gave it a different approach by trying to see what happened if you doubled more than $\log_{2}(N)$ times and I got that you needed more nodes that you actually had and eventually I worked backwards to get what you are saying. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I still dont get it. Can you explain a bit better? @Darwin57721 and FrankW

Comment: Please improve the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my approach to understand, mix of both visualization and mathematics.

In the weighted quick union, when we need to do union for two nodes, we join the roots of those two nodes ( basically the smaller tree joins the bigger tree ).

Lets say these are the two trees :-

```
                            1                    6
                           / \          and     / \
                          4   3                 5  2
                                                    \
                                                     7
```

Now lets say we need to perform union ( 3, 5) the resulting tree will look like this

```
                           6
                          /| \
                         1 5  2 
                        / \    \
                       4   3    7
```

Depth of node 3 increased by 1 during this operation but the depth of node 5 remained the same.

This means the depth of a node will only increase if the tree in which it is present joins a bigger tree.

Now whenever a small tree of size x ( no. of nodes in the tree) joins a bigger ( or equal sized ) tree, the size of result tree is at least 2 times x.

Now lets say this doubling of size happens i times, the size of resulting tree will be 2^i. Remember that whenever the size doubled the depth of some of the nodes increased by 1.

What is the maximum size the tree can obtain ?

```
   2^i   <=  n ( no. of nodes in the tree ) 
   i <= log n ( base 2 log operation )
```

Thus the depth of any node can be increased upto log n, not anymore than that.

Remember all the above logic only applies when a smaller tree joins a larger tree as its branch. Otherwise the **doubling logic** will not apply.

Comment: Great explanation ! There is just one thing that still escapes me, there is no explanation how we go from talking about "tree size" down to "depth" in the `i <= log n` line.

Comment: @sam  Check the line about the formula .  " ... whenever the size doubled the depth of some of the nodes increased by 1" .  This line is related to the tree size and depth.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is late to answer this question, just wanted to answer.
Here Let the total no. of elements be N. When you union two elements - a and b, you merge the two connected components: one component that contains a, and the other being that contains b. Here at the max you can double the resulting component(when both the components those contains a and b have same size). and Continuing like this - total number of components should be less than the number of time they are merged say i times. Now the maximum number of elements in terms of can be 2^i i.e. N < (2^i) => i > ln(N) ==> the maximum depth can be ln(N).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe explaining bottom-up might help to someone, as it did to me:

- Maximum height of a tree only increases when 2 trees with same height are
  merged.
- You can make maximum logN merges of such trees. (as you will have to keep dividing N with 2 to form i amount of such trees. At the example with N=8 below, you create equally sized trees to merge max 3 times.
- Therefore, depth of any node x is at most LogN. (due to max height)
- As you can see below, that happens first at the merge of (0,1), (0,2) and lastly (0,4).
  [image]